# Last modify for Custom meta data record

Tags: metadata, custom

Is it possible to get Last modify time for Custom Metadata Record?

I have a Custom metadata type - RR
in this  Custom metadata type, I have record - test
In this record I have a field - fff

My goal is to know when fff was updated last time.

Comment: This is not possible. See my comment against your later question for a way to approximate this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can get this information from **FieldDefinition**.

First get the **DurableId** from Custom Metadata:

> SELECT DurableId FROM EntityDefinition WHERE QualifiedApiName =
> 'CustomMetadataName__mdt'

Then search for the desired fields in **FieldDefinition**:

> SELECT QualifiedApiName, LastModifiedDate FROM FieldDefinition WHERE
> EntityDefinitionId = '<Mdt_DurableId>'

For more information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm

I hope I've helped. See ya!

Comment: Could you pls specify how to get LastModifyDate not when was created custom field on CMD type but when this field was changed on record.

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. How does this help you know the last modification date for the custom metadata type record and its fields (not the custom metadata type definition)?

Comment: @PhilW It works but gets Last modify (create time) of the custom field instead of Last modify of record.

Comment: But that is not what the quest asks for - this is not relevant as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

SystemModstamp is now available for Custom Metadata records.